# how to solve the conflict in jar files dependencies in Android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

hello guys i have a project that i migrated from eclipse to android studio today after importing the speedchecker library and as it shows the

```
speedchecker-android-sdk-1.2.jar
httpcore-4.3-beta1.jar
httpclient-4.3-beta1.jar
httpclient-cache-4.3-beta1.jar
httpmime-4.3-beta1.jar
```

are conflicting on some classes. these are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-google-http-client:1.4.14') {
    exclude module: 'commons-io'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons'
}
compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.19.0') {
    exclude module: 'commons-io'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
    exclude group: 'stax'
}
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile files('libs/activation.jar')

//conflict in here
compile files('libs/speedchecker-android-sdk-1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3-beta1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3-beta1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.3-beta1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3-beta1.jar')

compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/facebook1.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
}
```

can you please help me

Comment: Use `app:dependencies` to see the dependency tree. Normally it is pointed out which class is conflicting in the stacktrace. Search for that one and exclude it from one of your dependencies.

Comment: how to exclude a class from a jar file dependcy, and how to see this app:dependencies

Comment: I feel like it might be facebook1.jar or gcm.jar that is conflicting with your play-services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve the conflicts by overriding libraries as follows via your manifest:

Example, In the main android manifest :

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14" android:minSdkVersion="2"
              tools:overrideLibrary="com.example.lib1, com.example.lib2"/>
```

> **tools:overrideLibrary marker**
>
> A special marker that can only be used with uses-sdk declaration to
>   override importing a library which minimum SDK version is more recent
>   than that application's minimum SDK version. Without such a marker,
>   the manifest merger will fail. The marker will allow users to select
>   which libraries can be imported ignoring the minimum SDK version.

[Reference](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-tools:overrideLibrary-marker)

Answer (score 0):

Use `app:dependencies` to see the dependency tree. Normally it is pointed out which class is conflicting in the stacktrace. Search for that one and exclude it from one of your dependencies.

Open the `Gradle` window and click on `execute Task` (it's a icon). Type in `app:dependencies` and you will see your gradle tree in the `Messages` window.

Search the conflicting class and exclude it like this for e.g.:

```
 compile('commons-validator:commons-validator:1.5.0') {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }
```